# Sai do meu estágio e me removeram como colaborador, perdi todos meus commits no meu histórico

Tags: git, github

Galera, trabalhei por 7 meses em uma empresa e depois que meu contrato acabou me tiraram como colaborador. Eu tinha em torno de 100 commits no projeto privado deles, porém todos eles sumiram do meu perfil do git. Alguém sabe se tem como eu ter no meu perfil minhas contribuições privadas de volta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do GitHub](https://github.com/blog/2173-more-contributions-on-your-profile):

> Private contributions are not shown by default and, when enabled, are completely anonymized to the general public. [...] Details of the issues, pull requests, and commits you have made on private repositories are only visible to your fellow repository collaborators.

Ou em tradução literal:

> As contribuições privadas não são apresentadas por padrão e, quando ativadas, são completamente anonimizadas para o público em geral. [...] Os detalhes de *issues*, *pull requests*  e *commits* que você realizou em repositórios privados só são visíveis para seus colegas colaboradores de repositório.

Ou seja - tanto os administradores do projeto precisam habilitar a visualização anonimizada, quanto você precisa selecionar '*Public and Private Contributions*' no painel de visualização de contribuições. Se eles não ativarem, seu conteúdo não pode ser visualizado no seu perfil.

Comment: É q antes os commits, mesmo com detalhes privados aos colaboradores, apareciam no meu github. Aparecia la pras pessoas fulano fez 100+ contribuições em repositorio privado. Porem desde minha remoção do repositorio isso sumiu do meu perfil tanto pra mim quanto para as pessoas. Eu só queria que aparecesse de volta isso, pq meu git no momento ta zerado ja q era meu primeiro estágio :)

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente não... Como você mesmo disse, o repositório é privado, de forma que, se você foi removido dele, o github desconsidera todas as suas contribuições ao mesmo.

No entanto, você pode continuar contribuindo com códigos open source! É uma ótima forma de aprender, e não será removida da sua lista de contribuições, somente se o projeto for deletado (mas seu fork vai se manter). Lembre-se, quantidade de contribuições não é uma métrica para qualidade de software ou para a *skill* do programador, por exemplo, eu posso fazer 5000 commits inúteis, enquanto outra pessoa pode solucionar um grande problema em apenas 1.

Um bom programador não é aquele que tem mais contribuições, mas aquele que sabe o que está fazendo e gosta do que faz.

Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow PT!